# Colloidal Silver?

Tags: home-experiment

There are a lot of tutorials on the net on how to make colloidal silver. Many of them basically go like this - Hook up two 99.99% silver coins or wires to three 9V batteries, and put the silver in saline, an inch apart, for a few minutes. Does this make real colloidal silver or silver ionic silver or silver chloride?

Here's an example:
http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-make-COLLOIDAL-SILVER-Easy/

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! To acquaint yourself with this page, take the [tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help). Furthermore [this tutorial](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/88/189) shows you how math and chemical formulae can be nicely formatted on this site.

Comment: I hope you don't plan to ingest colloidal silver, it can turn you [blue](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/americas/2297471.stm).